# Can't load a package that used to load

Tags: packages

I created and used a package a number of years ago, *Mathematica* 3.0, and I am now trying to load and use that package under *Mathematica* 10.0.  I had to clear up some function name conflicts that had arisen with the newer versions of *Mathematica*, but my package will not load.

> Needs::nocont: Context "EE`varyprcs`" was not created when Needs was evaluated. >>

I know the path is correct because another package in the same location does load.

I am not a *Mathematica* expert, but would like guidance for common pitfalls that would make a package not load that used to load.

Comment: Could you copy and paste your `Needs` call here exactly as you used it? Did it load under v9?